# Unable to view WPF designer ("Invalid Markup")

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I just installed Visual Studio 2019 (previously used 2017) and it seems that since I did this, I can't view any WPF files in the designer.

It just displays

> Invalid Markup
>
> Check the Error List for more information.

This even happens on a brand new project (.NET 4.8) with nothing in it. Note that it builds and runs fine.

The errors in the code window are

> Window is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project

and

> Grid is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project

(That is, of course, in my new blank project - my actual work project contains many more similar errors).

What I've tried (per various suggestions found around the Internet)

- Delete my ShadowCache directory
- Kill the Microsoft Visual Studio XAML Designer process and restart from within Visual Studio
- Opening the project in Visual Studio 2017 (still installed) - It's now happening here too although prior to the 2019 install I'm certain it was fine. Also, create a new project in 2017.
- Change .NET version to 4.6
- Clean / Rebuild, Restart Visual Studio, Restart my PC
- Ensure I have a reference to System.Xaml in my project.
- Sacrificing a lamb

I've also found reference to a bug that was apparently fixed by MS in 2021 - but I've only just downloaded and installed it today.

This is the code of the MainWindow.xaml, for reference:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfMessing.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfMessing"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Did you select _Install while downloading_ or _Download all, then install_? I recommend the second one. Did you install the necessary _Workloads_ and _Individual Components_? Have you tried repairing Visual Studio using _Visual Studio Installer_? You may also try uninstalling and re-installing Visual Studio. The following may also be of interest: [Uninstall or remove Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

Comment: @user246821 - Thanks - Tried uninstalling & reinstalling with "Download all, then install" - then tried InstallCleanup (as advised in your link) and reinstalled... still no luck

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

Comment: You can try to use .net 6.0's WPF to test whether the designer can be opened normally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need a reference to PresentationFramework and WindowsBase. These come with a Windows Application project type but not a class library.

Comment: Already have a reference to both of these (it was a WPF application project type)